# Bayes Theorem - one event dependent on two

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I do have problems to put up the Bayes Theorem for one event depending on two:
$\mathbb{P}(q|z,x)$.
Two events depending on one was still ok,
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(x,q|z) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(z|x,q) }{\mathbb{P}(z))} \mathbb{P}(x|z) \mathbb{P}(q)
\end{equation*}.

Can somebody please help me with that?

Comment: Should the second-last term be $P(x|q)$ instead of $P(x|z)$?

Comment: You're right, my mistake, sorry and thank you.

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? What exactly do you want to do? Prove that something is a true? Deduce an equation? I don't understand

Comment: @William The goal is to formulate the Bayes Theorem in such a way, that parameter estimation via the Bayes update (-> (ensemble) Kalman Filter) becomes deriveable. In this case $x$ is the initial state and $z$ is a measurement. $q$ shall be identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here $x$, $q$ and $z$ are just labels for events. You can just reassigns them so you have:
$$
\mathbb{P}(z,x|q) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(q|z,x) }{\mathbb{P}(q)} \mathbb{P}(z|x) \mathbb{P}(x)
$$
Now rearrange.

You can also derive all of these relations from first principals by going back to looking at $\mathbb{P}(z,x,q)$ (the order of $z,x,q$ is arbitary and they can be reordered at will). Then:
$$
\mathbb{P}(z,x,q)=\mathbb{P}(z,x|q)\mathbb{P}(q)=\mathbb{P}(q|z,x)\mathbb{P}(z,x)=\mathbb{P}(q|z,x)\mathbb{P}(z|x)\mathbb{P}(x)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, that cleared up a lot.
Another question, is it possible to split up $\mathbb{P}(z|x)$ so that $\mathbb{P}(q|z,x)$ is only dependent on $\mathbb{P}(x)$ and $\mathbb{P}(z)$?

Comment: @ChaoticPolynomial I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is no different in this case:
$$P(q | z, x) = \frac{P(z, x | q)P(q)}{P(z, x)}$$
You can further break down $P(z, x)$ as
$$P(z, x) = P(z | x)P(x) = P(x | z)P(z)$$